# aws cloudformation Error occurred during build: Yum does not have gcc available for installation

Tags: templates, amazon-web-services, metadata, yum

I'm creating a template to preinstall specific packages. The template can start the instance and security group but nothing is getting installed. When running

```
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s SIM --access-key=XXX --secret-key=XXX --region us-west-2  -r WebServer
```

I get:
Error occurred during build: Yum does not have gcc  available for installation

```
"Resources": {
        "WebServer": {
            "Metadata" : {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
                    "config" : {
                           "packages" : {
                          "yum" : {
                        "gcc " : [],
                        "make" : [],
                        "gcc-c++" : [],
                        "nginx" : [],
                        "zlib" : [],
                        "zlib-devel" : [],
                        "rubygems" : [],
                        "git-core" : [],
                        "selinux-policy-targeted" : [],
                        "selinux-policy-devel" : [],
                        "libmemcached" : [],
                        "libmemcached-devel" : []
                            }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm getting the same error with "Error occurred during build: Yum does not have java-1.8.0 available for installation". But I ssh'ed into the workstation and it worked just fine when I ran manually. I'm guessing it's trying to do stuff before the public ip is working on the network interface? How did you resolve this?